# sam local invoke failling after aws samcli 1.21 upgrade

Tags: aws-lambda, sam

after upgrading sam cli from 0.52 to 1.21 sam local invoke falling with below error

Error: Could not find amazon/aws-sam-cli-emulation-image-python3.8:rapid-1.21.1 image locally and failed to pull it from docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a manual docker pull for the latest tag and then it started working. The command would be as follows:
`docker pull amazon/aws-sam-cli-emulation-image-python3.8`